# When does $A_1 A_2 A_3\ldots \xrightarrow{a.s}0$ for IID random matrices $A_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, random-matrices, stability-theory, matrix-analysis

Suppose $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots$ is an infinite sequence of $d\times d$ matrices sampled IID from some distribution. Under which conditions does the product converge to zero almost surely?

The hard case is when $A_i$ are rank-deficient so matrix logarithm is not defined. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/430790/7655) one such case is addressed with $A=I-x_ix_i^T$ and isotropic 2-D Gaussian $x_i$. Can this be generalized?

Comment: Is it your question equivalent to the following question:      assuming we pick up random matrix every one second what is the average time   after which sequential multiplication of all matrices generates zero matrix?

Comment: ah, the wording was ambiguous, changed "when" to "under which conditions"

Comment: The rate at which this product converges is the Lyapunov exponent which is [hard to compute](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdbl/lyapunov.pdf). I just need to know if Lyapunov exponent is negative, so curious at what techniques I can use here, more general than the approach used in mathoverflow [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430781/range-of-a-such-that-w-leftarrow-w-a-x-langle-w-x-rangle-converges-almos/430790#430790)

Comment: Have you considered the simplest case of $1 \times 1$ matrices ? What are the results?

Comment: @Widawensen for scalars we can take logs, infinite product becomes a sum, and we get the answer from the central limit theorem

Comment: It feels like the condition should be that the matrix $E[\log A]$ has only negative eigenvalues